# Generating a string of values from a set of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a word matching exercise that takes a set of inputs. The program reads the html from the input boxes. Then the html is displayed in a textarea element. When the user clicks "Show Answer" the set of keys and descriptions are to be displayed

A screenshot of the output looks like
[image]

The method that generates the string for the answer is written like so

```
//has the html already been generated? 
    if(!htmlGenerated){
        //fetch the results box
        results = document.getElementById("results");
        
        //create textarea
        textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.setAttribute("id","generated_html_textarea");
        
        // initialize blank html
        header = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>Word Matching Exercise</title>\n\t\t<style>\n*:focus {outline: 2px solid blue; outline-offset: 2px;}\n\t\tdetails {padding:3px;}\n\t\t</style>\n\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/boxes.css\" />\n\t\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/event1.js\">';
        header += "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/style.css\" />"
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-89940905-27\">'
        // header += '</'
        // header += 'script>\n<script>\n\t window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n\t function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};\tgtag(\"js\", new Date());\tgtag(\"config\", \"UA-89940905-27\");\n'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/event1.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.alerts.js">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n'
        header += '<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">'
        header += '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/logging.js\">'
        header += '</'
        header += 'script>\n</head>\n\t\t<body>';
        let html = '';
        html += header;
        html += '<div id=\'maincontentstyle\'>\n'
        html += '\t<center>\n'
        html += '\t\t<div id=\'boxstyle\'>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t<h3 id=\'title\'>'+title+"</h3>\n";
        //create key inputs
        html += '\t\t\t\t<center>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\'source\'>\n' 
        console.log("The value of the dlArray is")
        console.log(dlArray)
        console.log("The value of the elArray is")
        console.log(elArray)
        dlArray = shuffle(dlArray);
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < elArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id=\'s';
        id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
        html += id;
        html +='\' class=\'draggyBox-small ui-draggable\'>\n';
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
        html += elArray[i-numberOfInputs]
        html += '\n';
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n';
        }
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</center>\n'

        //create description inputs
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t<table id=\'tablestyle\'>\n'
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id=\'row';
        id   = (1+i-numberOfInputs);
        html += id;
        html +='\'>\n';
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div id=\'t';
        html += id;
        html +='\' class=\'ltarget ui-droppable\'>'
        html +='</div>\n' 
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</td >\n'
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id=\'d'
        html += id
        html += '\'>\n'
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t';
        html += dlArray[i-numberOfInputs];
        html += '\n';
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td >\n' 
        html +='\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n';
        }
        html += '\t\t\t\t\t</table>\n';
        html += '\t\t\t\t</center>\n'
        html += '\t\t</div>\n'
        html += '\t</center>\n'
        html += '</div>'
        html += '<span style=\"padding: 3px\"> <button id =\"one\" class=\"button\" type=\"button\" onClick=\"show_answer'
        html += '()'
        html += '"'
        html += ">"
        html += 'Show Answer'
        html += '</'
        html += 'button> <button id = \"resetButton\" class=\"button\" type=\"button\" onClick=\"reset'
        html += '()'
        html += '"'
        html += '>'
        html += 'Reset'
        html += '</'
        html += 'button>'
        html += '</span>'
        footer = '\n\t\t</body>\n</html>\n';
        footer += ''
        footer += '<script type="text/javascript">'
        footer += '$(init);'
        footer += '$( window ).unload(function() {'
        footer += 'removeStorage.removeItem("someVarKey1");'
        footer += '});'
        footer += 'function reset() {'
        footer += '  var someVarName = true;'
        footer += 'sessionStorage.setItem("someVarKey1", someVarName);'
        footer += 'window.location.reload();'
        footer += '}'
        footer += 'function init() {'
        footer += ' document.getElementById(\'resetButton\').style.display = \'none\';'
        footer += 'document.getElementById("resetButton").style.visibility = "hidden";'
        footer += 'if (false && sessionStorage.getItem("someVarKey1"))'
        footer += '$("#one").focus();'
        footer += 'var numbers = ['
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++){
            footer += dlArray[i-numberOfInputs].replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
            footer += ',';
        } 
        footer += '];'
        footer += 'initialize(numbers);'
        footer += '}'
        footer += '</script>'
        footer += '  <script>'
        footer += '  answer = '
        footer += '\"'
        answer = '';
        for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++) {
            answer += elArray[i-numberOfInputs];
            console.log(answer)
            answer += ':';
            answer += dlArray[numberOfInputs-i];
            console.log(answer)
            answer  += ' '
        }
        footer += answer
        console.log(answer)
        footer += '\"'
        footer += ';'
        // footer += '\n'
        // footer += ' Iteration: is one time execution of the loop body.'
        // footer += '\n'
        // footer += 'Loop Continuation Condition: is a Boolean expression that controls the execution of the loop.'
        // footer += '\n'
        // footer += 'Infinite Loop: is a loop that runs forever due to an error in the code.'
        // footor += '\n'
        // footer += 'Off-by-one: is an error in the program that causes the loop body to be executed one more or less time."'
        footer += '  function show_answer() {'
        footer += '   jAlert(answer, \'Correct Match\');'
        footer += '  }'
        footer += '</script>'
        footer += ' '
        footer += '<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/GetElementPosition3.js"></script>'
        footer += ' <script>'
        footer += '//    $(function(){'
        footer += '//  if (\'speechSynthesis\' in window) {'
        footer += '//    speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {'
        footer += '//      var $voicelist = $(\'#voices\');'
        footer += '//'
        footer += '//      if($voicelist.find(\'option\').length == 0) {'
        footer += '//        speechSynthesis.getVoices().forEach(function(voice, \'index) {'
        footer += '//          var $option = $(\'<option>\')'
        footer += '//          .val(index)'
        footer += '//          .html(voice.name + (voice.default ? \' (default)\' :\'\'));'
        footer += '//'
        footer += '//          $voicelist.append($option);'
        footer += '//        });'
        footer += '//'
        footer += '//        $voicelist.material_select();'
        footer += '//      }'
        footer += '//    }'
        footer += '//  } '
        footer += '//});     '
        footer += 'audioOn = false;'
        footer += '$(function() {'
        footer += '$(\'.menulink\').click(function(){'
        footer += '  if (audioOn) {'
        footer += ' $("#bg").attr(\'src\',"audioOff.png");  '
        footer += ' audioOn = false;'
        footer += '  }'
        footer += '  else {'
        footer += ' $("#bg").attr(\'src\',"audioOn.png");'
        footer += ' audioOn = true; speak(" ");'
        footer += '  }'
        footer += '  return false;'
        footer += '});'
        footer += '});'
        footer += ' </script>   '
        html += footer;

        // html generation is done.
        htmlGenerated = true;
        textarea.value = html;
        results.replaceChildren(textarea);

        // Generate reset, show answer, , and render html buttons
        controls = document.createElement("div");
        controls.setAttribute("id","program1");
        controls.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
        controls.innerHTML +=  '<button id = "renderHTMLButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="render_html()">Render html</button>\n';
        controls.innerHTML +=  '<button id = "submit" class="button" type="button" onClick="saveContent()"> Save </button>\n';
        controls.innerHTML +=  `<button id=\"view_button\" class=\"button\" style=\" display: none;\"><a href=\"${window.location.href}/${saved_id}\"> view</a> </button>\n`;
        if(document.getElementById("renderHTMLButton"))
            results.parentNode.replaceChild(controls);
            results.parentNode.appendChild(controls);
        }
    }
```

This is where the problem is

```
for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length+numberOfInputs; i++) {
            answer += elArray[i-numberOfInputs];
            console.log(answer)
            answer += ':';
            answer += dlArray[numberOfInputs-i];
            console.log(answer)
            answer  += ' '
        }
```

The console log output returns

```
k1:d1
word_match.js:189 k1:d1 k2
word_match.js:192 k1:d1 k2:undefined
word_match.js:196 k1:d1 k2:undefined
```

Expected:

```
k1:d1 k2:k2 k3:k3
```

Actual:

```
k1:d1 k2:undefined k3:undefined
```

Any help understanding why this error keeps appearing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please click [edit] and make a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: In the last for loop try and change `answer += dlArray[numberOfInputs-i];` to `answer += dlArray[i-numberOfInputs];` and see what happens.